# Power spliter for Raspberry pi and servo motor

Tags: power-supply, power, raspberry-pi, servo

I have a raspberry pi. I want to control a 12 volt motor (low torque). I believe the motor only has two connectors, and when it is powered it goes. The motor goes off of 12 volts where as the Raspberry Pi is only 5 volts.

I also want to be able to power the motor and the raspberry pi in one unit. I don't know what this yellow box is. For example, do I split the 12 volts DC coming in, and send 12 volts to the motor and then do some resisters to lower the 12 volts to 5 volts to power the raspberry pi? What about the ground for the motor? Can it be connected back to the yellow box too? (what ever the yellow box is)

For more clarification:

[image]

Comment: I strongly recommend that you look at the comments which have now been moved to chat [**here**](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113598/discussion-on-question-by-matthew-power-spliter-for-raspberry-pi-and-servo-motor). The discussion was interesting but peripheral to the main topic.

Comment: Matthew: It will greatly help people help you if you provide web links to anything you are using . The term "servo" can cover several quite different motor types and power and voltage and drive requirements for what you are probably using vary. Please provide brand & model of your servo motor and a web link to a data sheet (or a technical description if data sheet not available). A web link to a Pi Zero datasheet would also do no harm. || Note that what Chris says is valid - to get a good answer that works it is necessary to be sure of what the real requirement is.

Comment: Do you need to have closed loop positioning, or just spin the motor?  In one direction or both?  Also for this type of motor we really need the current or power rating, it should have a name plate...

Comment: I just need to spin the motor, one direction, for about a second. It is for an automatic food dispenser, so just a burst for a second or so, and I don't know exactly what type of motor I need for that.

Comment: @Matthew Do you have a motor brand / model/weblink?

Comment: @Matthew, At first you wrote "servo motor" in the question; after that, you put the photo of a DC motor; after that, the photo in the question was changed again to a new kind of motor.

Comment: In my own opinion, the correct way of making a pet feeder project is **make the physical fixtures first**, i.e., the physical (3d printed? wood?) parts that, controlled by the motor, will release the food. Only after the motor is chosen and bought, and the motor is efficiently attached to the physical parts, you can start to think about how the electronics to power and to control this motor.

Comment: Every kind of motor has different specs and requirements. You need to define what you expect from the motor for this project and choose a motor according this definition. This is the reason why the physical fixture has to be built before. Will you use a servo motor? Will you use a common DC motor? Or a brushless DC motor? Or a stepper motor?

Comment: Even when you say "I just need to spin the motor, one direction, for about a second.", this phrase lacks some need information for deciding what kind of motor. How many rotations in this movement? What is the desired speed of this movement (RPM)? How much force (torque) the motor has to apply when doing this movement? These are the reasons for defining the physical fixtures before chosing the kind of motor that your project needs.

Comment: I can read from the picture that the motor with cast aluminium case, is geared, less than 30 rpm, 6mm shaft diameter, torque above 15 kgcm, definitely it is an over kill.

Comment: This 3 minutes video suggest the motor and solenoid valve (for water) you may like to consider: (1) Homemade Dog Feeder with Arduino 2015oct26, 27,983 Views
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcqbZ_y5WI0.

Answer (score 2):

@mguima has provided a [useful link](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-8-using-a-servo-motor/hardware) in his answer. BUT do note Chris Stratton's comments also.

Important considerations include:

- Any motor tends to make electrical "noise" which a microcontroller is very sensitive to.
- Usually the power needs of a motor exceed that which what can sensibly be fed from a Pi header directly.
- The servo voltage needs to be correct and may not match the Pi supply.

Overall, when starting off, supplying the servo from a separate supply, batteries or other is a safe move.

Grounds of Pi supply and servo supply **MUST** be connected.

The servo control lead can usually be driven directly by the Pi.

Comment: The question uses the term "servomotor" which tends to be associated with traditional industrial devices.  It does not say "hobby servo" so it's not appropriate to be assuming that the asker is speaking of a hobby servo.  The whole point of EESE is that we don't guess what someone is asking about, we wait for them to provided the critically needed information.  Normally that would be electrical specifications; if it actually *is* a hobby servo then identifying the brand or model or providing a picture, would at least let people know which set of collected knowledge is applicable.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Again, I largely agree with you. In a level-playing-field discussion your suggested approach is the greatly preferred one. I also initially took "servomotor" to mean a traditional 'servo'. It took mguima's comment to trigger the mentat mode (Dune, about 35% of necessary facts for a usually right solution :-) ) to realise that with high probability he means a hobby servo. I certainly do not know with certainty. | I agree that what I am doing is a non ideal approach on a level playing field. I also consider that for a beginner with obviously very limited technical knowledge ...

Comment: ... 'getting them comfortably to the table where we can talk' probably requires a slightly different approach. I value technical rigour about as much as the great Olin Lathrop. Getting there I may favour a different path in order not to lose victims along the way :-) :-(.

Comment: @ChrisStratton I keep meaning to ask - are you the person with the same name that I knew in NZ decades ago, or someone else?

Answer (score 2):

> I just need to spin the motor, one direction, for about a second. It is for an automatic food dispenser, so just a burst for a second or so

Unidirectional control of a DC motor is typically accomplished with an N-FET switching the motor's negative power lead, while the positive remains permanently connected to the supply.

Many of the best modern FETs for this kind of role are in surface mount packages, but if you prefer a through-hole package, Adafruit sells the [IRLB8721PBF (data sheet)](https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/irlb8721pbf.pdf) for this type of purpose.  The main factor of importance is not the ultimate current rating, but rather that with the 3.3 volts the pi can supply to the FET gate, the FET will be reasonably (and not just minimally) "on".

Given that a motor is an inductive load which exhibits a "kick" when turned off, you'll also need a diode "backwards" across the motor.

And you'll want a 10K or so pull-down resistor on the FET gate.

Some might suggest using a relay module for this task; that is a path you can pursue but there have been some anecodotal reports of the cheap undocumented e-commerce site relay modules sometimes not working reliably with 3.3 volt input, as they sometimes have optocouplers set up in a way that assumes 5 volt logic from an Arduino.  The potential isolation provided by a relay and optocoupler is substantially (if not entirely) defeated when you use the same power supply for both the computer and the motor.

(Incidentally, if you could use an Arduino, that would probably make your project a lot more robust than a pi, which as extremely complex system with far more things that can go wrong).

> and I don't know exactly what type of motor I need for that

This is worrisome, until you've picked the motor it's impossible to say much of anything about power supply requirements.  Fortunately TO-220 size FET's are likely overkill for the switching requirement.   Your picture made it seem like you were considering a gear motor, which could indeed be a good choice for slow one-way movement.

> For example, do I split the 12 volts DC coming in, and send 12 volts to the motor and then do some resisters to lower the 12 volts to 5 volts to power the raspberry pi?

Loads of time-varying power requirement like a Raspberry Pi cannot be supplied through a resistor.  They'd need a voltage regulator.  In the very old days a Linear Voltage regulator (which is basically a resistor which self adjusts for load) might have been used, but a pi consumes so much power that this would generate a lot of heat.  So today, instead you would use a Switching Regulator.   The LM2596 is a relatively old and not terribly sophisticated part compared to what is on the market for such purposes now, but it would *probably* work, and the Internet is full of places selling modules with something *comparable* (if not literally) that on them.  Pick one where any adjustment is via a screw type potentiometer and carefully pre-set it while measuring the output voltage; you don't want something that will fry your pi if bumped out of adjustment.

Comment: This has been very helpful. Thank you. I will continue to research!